# How to draw a vertical line down the middle of JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, drawing, graphics2d

I am looking to draw a line down the middle of my frame between the users info and the JButtons.

[image]

I don't know much about drawing in java. I done some looking up already on how to do this but no suggestions sufficed. 
I read on another question to use a painComponent(graphic g) method to paint over the gui but i couldn't get it to work. 
My college lecture slides and examples don't provide much help.
Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: [How to use Separators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/separator.html)

Comment: Use LayoutManaers, setting the gap to some pixels or adding rigid elements (for BoxLayout) can create a visual separator.

Comment: @maraca Im not using Layout Managers, im using absolute positioning for the information panel and the buttons panel.

Comment: Quick and dirty: add another absolute positioned panel/label which is very thin and high. Although it would be better to use layout managers.

Comment: @maraca I got it, just used 
        public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
         super.paint(g); 
         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
         //Thickens the line
         g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3));
         //Set the positioning of the line
         Line2D lin = new Line2D.Float(735, 825, 735, 240);
         g2.draw(lin);
     }